# Do we name each element in this Array?

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, cs50

For this problem, I need to match the names that people enter to a ballot which will then count as a vote.

There is a structure called candidate and I am trying to create an array of this structure to act as the ballot. Here is the code:

```
typedef struct
{
    string name;
    int votes;
}
candidate;

// Array of candidates
candidate candidates[MAX];

candidates.name[0] = "Sam";
candidates.votes[0] = 0;

candidates.name[1] = "Stan";
candidates.votes[1] = 0;

candidates.name[2] = "Sara";
candidates.votes[2] = 0;
```

When I compile the code an error pops up that says there is a specifier missing but it has been previously defined in the structure.

I looked at other examples of code for this problem and people did not do this step so it's probably unnecessary but even then I'm unsure as to why.

Here is the rest of the code.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// Candidates have name and vote count
typedef struct
{
    string name;
    int votes;
}
candidate;

// Array of candidates
candidate candidates[MAX];

candidates[0].name = "Sam";
candidates[0].votes = 0;

candidates[1].name= "Stan";
candidates[1].votes = 0;

candidates[2].name = "Sara";
candidates[2].votes = 0;

// Number of candidates
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(string name);
void print_winner(void);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: plurality [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1];
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
    }

    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    // Loop over all voters
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        string name = get_string("Vote: ");

        // Check for invalid vote
        if (!vote(name))
        {
            printf("Invalid vote.\n");
        }
    }

    // Display winner of election
    print_winner();
}

// Update vote totals given a new vote
bool vote(string name)
{
    // TODO
    return false;
}

// Print the winner (or winners) of the election
void print_winner(void)
{
    // TODO
    return;
}
```

Comment: Statements such as the assignment expression statement `candidates[0].name = "Sam";` need to be inside a function body. You don't need that code though, because you fill in the names in `main` from the command-line parameters

Comment: In the first example you use `candidates.name[0] = "Sam";` in the second (full) code you use `candidates[0].name = "Sam";`. What is now the code you try to compile? And for which line of code pops which error exactly up?

Comment: what is `string` ?

Comment: @P__J__ Alias for `char *` - `cs50.h` header.

Comment: Others likely didn't do this step because the spec says "_You should not modify anything else in plurality.c other than the implementations of the vote and print_winner functions_"

Answer (score 1):

A few things to mention.

#### 1.

In the first example you use the subscript operator at the wrong place, at the member:

```
candidates.name[0] = "Sam";
candidates.votes[0] = 0;

candidates.name[1] = "Stan";
candidates.votes[1] = 0;

candidates.name[2] = "Sara";
candidates.votes[2] = 0;
```

This wrong. The array index is for the array of structures `candidates`.

#### 2.

You use assignments to the struct members at global scope.

```
candidates[0].name = "Sam";
candidates[0].votes = 0;

candidates[1].name= "Stan";
candidates[1].votes = 0;

candidates[2].name = "Sara";
candidates[2].votes = 0;
```

(second example)

This is not permissible in C. Assignments like that need to be inside of a function.

---

Side note:

- `string` is an `cs50.h` alias for `char *`. So the member `name` is only a pointer and you assign the pointer to point to a string literal, which might not be the best thing for what you want to do. Maybe you want to use an array of `char` instead, which really stores the string and is changeable without memory loss. The pointers are be able to point to different string literals or strings too, but you have memory leaks if you change the pointed content then because the previous assigned string literals are still alive in memory and waste there unnecessary space.

Answer (score 0):

`candidates` is the array you want to index.

```
candidates.name[0]
```

should be

```
candidates[0].name
```

etc

You actually did it right in the second snippet. In the future, please don't post code unrelated to the problem!

Answer (score 0):

If string is an **array of chars** then

`strcpy(candidates[0].name, "Something");`

If string is an **pointer to char** then

`candidates[0].name = "Something";`

Comment: It's the latter.